# Add new row of component after button clicked using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to add new row of components after clicking a button located in a previous row.

This figure:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkbZf.png]

shows the row that I want to replicate on the next row after I click the 'Add' button.

What I tried to do gives me this result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zgWR.png]

but only after I first clicked the 'Add' button and then the item selection is done.

How can I make the 'Add' button independent from the other components and how can I adjust the visualization?

Here is the code:

```
////// First row
    // First Column
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    this.add(this.field, gbc);

    // Second Column
    gbc.gridx++;
    this.add(this.operator, gbc);

    // Third Column
    gbc.gridx++;
    this.add(this.value, gbc);

    ////// Second row
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    this.add(rowNumber, gbc);

    // First Column
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// SET DIMENSION
    attrList.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    this.add(attrList, gbc);

    // Second Column
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////// SET DIMENSION
    opListString.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXX");
    this.add(opListString, gbc);

    // Third Column (Hidden)
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////SET DIMENSION
    sessoBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    this.add(sessoBox, gbc);
    sessoBox.setVisible(false);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////SET DIMENSION
    titoloBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    this.add(titoloBox, gbc);
    titoloBox.setVisible(false);


    // Fourth Column
    gbc.gridx = 4;
    remButton = new JButton("Rem");
    this.add(remButton, gbc);

    // Add row JButton
    gbc.gridx = 5;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    this.add(addRow, gbc);

    // Add empty JLabel to positioning components at the top
    gbc.weighty = 10;
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    this.add(emptyLabel, gbc);

    // Add Action Listener on Attributes to choose
    // Display Value Components based on item selected
    attrList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String choose = attrList.getSelectedItem().toString();

            switch(choose) {
            case "----------------": {
                removeItem();
                break;
            }
            case "Sex": {
                removeItem();
                addOpsString();
                addValueComp2(sessoBox);
            }
            }
        }
        });

    // Remove row
    /*remButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            remButton.remove((addRow));
        }
    });
    */

    // Add row
    addRow.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            gbc.gridy = ++rowNum;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            panel.remove(emptyLabel);
            panel.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(rowNum)), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(attrList);
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(opListString);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(remButton);
            gbc.gridx++;
            panel.add(addRow);

            // Add empty JLabel to positioning components at the top
            gbc.weighty = 10;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = rowNum + 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
            panel.add(emptyLabel, gbc);
        }
    });
```

Comment: 1) That task seems better suited to a `JTable`. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: This is not a direct answer - but for any Swing layout task, I just use MigLayout: http://www.miglayout.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to replicate the entire row, you should probably set up each row as a component such as a JTable or JPanel, and then place each of those components inside another JPanel or a JFrame.  Then you can use the Object.clone() method to create each new component (row).  You may need to pack() or validate() the new outside component when you add a row, especially if the size of the outside window is changed.

Alternatively, if you have a finite number of objects, you can create them all when you initialize and use setVisible() to show each one when needed.